# Filter the n columns with highest occurence of a value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame where every column either has True or Nan in each row. I am looking for a way to filter the 10 columns with the most occurrences of true.

Comment: `df.sum().nlargest(10).index`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random


num_rows = 50
num_cols = 10

df = pd.DataFrame({f'col{i}': [random.choice([True, np.NaN]) for j in range(num_rows)] for i in range(num_cols)})
df.iloc[:, :10].count().idxmax()
```